# How can my users add sprite and image resources once my app is deployed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a Unity 2D game. Users can select one of 12 characters to play. The character sprites are contained in a single graphics file that I have in the Resources folder, from which I then sliced them into individual sprites. The player will bring up a scrolling selection panel (think gallery) and click on the character they wish to play.

Once my game is deployed, I'd like users to be able to add new characters, perhaps from in-game purchases.

In my old Windows version, it was simple: add the individual bitmaps into the appropriate directory, then just read all of them.

How would I do this in Unity/C# such that users acquire the new character pack and it gets integrated into the game and the sprites added to the bottom of the scrolling selection panel? I can't find any discussion of this. Feel free to point me to a tutorial, if one's out there.

Comment: It would be an odd workflow to buy IAP only to have to import into the game yourself. You can use standard File I/O for this if you want to, but it would be better if you had a server that the game could poll for DLC content.

Comment: kindly mark the answer as solved if it helped you thanks.

Comment: Can you point me to a resource that discusses how/where to set up a server, and how to link that to in-app purchases? And what is DLC content? (This is my first Unity project, though I come from a game development background, but it's been a few years.)

Comment: DLC = downloadable content. The topic of CDN (content delivery network) architecture could fill textbooks. I'd look into CDNs and Unity's AddressableAsset system to start

Comment: Great, thanks for the info. It's hard to get relevant search results without knowing the proper terminology.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to save changes to the disk. 
.Net has the System.IO namespace for you to use for reading and writing to disk.

Because you can write to the disk during run time there will be no problems calling those resources.

You can check Brackeys on YouTube they teach a lot if you are new to unity
here is how you save and load data in unity 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOjd_qU2Ido

Comment: I'm already saving my game data: player names, stats, etc. I need to understand how users can add new resources (sprites, images, etc.) to the game AFTER purchasing it. I recognize that may be a bigger topic than can be answered here, but a link to a tutorial would be really helpful.

Comment: there are many IAP videos on youtube like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iU8tP1BAdyM

Comment: you can search unity IAP on youtube and change the filter to this year and you will get recent updated videos

Comment: Great, I'll give them a watch.